# DiscordJS Verify command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to create a verify Command with discord.js v12 which gives you a verified Role which is defined in a Configfile.

Configfile:

```
{
"token": "my-token",
"status": "a game",
"statusurl": "",
"statustype": 0,
"botmanager": ["285470267549941761", "743136148293025864"],
"prefix": "m!",
"server": {
    "343308714423484416": {
        "active": true,
        "hasBeta": true,
        "adminroles": ["533646738813353984"],
        "modroles": ["744589796361502774"],
        "premiumtoken": "",
        "welcomechannel": "653290718248435732",
        "welcomemessage": "Hey Hey %user% at %server%",
        "welcomemsgenabled": true,
        "leavechannel": "653290718248435732",
        "leavemessage": "Bye %user% at %server%",
        "leavemsgenabled": true,
        "verifiedrole": "533646700712296448",
        "ruleschannel": "382197929605201920"
    }
}
```

}

My Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const config = require('./config.json')

client.on('ready', () => {
    client.user.setStatus('online')
    client.user.setActivity("m!help")
    console.log(`Bot started successfully in ${client.guilds.cache.size} Guilds with ${client.users.cache.size} Users and ${client.channels.cache.size} Channels`)
})

client.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
            if(command === "verify") {
                if(args.length == 0) {
                    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
                    if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r=>[config.server[(message.guild.id)].modroles].includes(r.id))) {
                        if(!member) {
                            return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor(0xd35400).setTitle("Invalid User").setDescription("Please use the following Syntax:\n `m!verify <Nutzer>`"))
                        } else {
                            var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.id === config.server[(message.guild.id)].verifiedrole);
                            member.roles.cache.add(config.guild[(message.guild.id)].verifiedrole)
                        }
                    } else {
                        message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle("Missing Perms!").setDescription("You're missing the permission to execute this command!").setColor(0xe74c3c))               
                    }
                }
            }

            console.log("Command used: " + command + " " + args + " | User: " + message.author.id + " | Guild: " + message.guild.id)
        }
    }
})

client.login(config.token)
```

I removed the most Code so only this command is left. Important is, that this Bot have to be able to use at multiple Servers at the time.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so lets make this a multi part answer. First "What is wrong here?" Well, for the most part your current code does not work because you don't use the brackets correctly. You are trying to close brackets that you don't open anywhere. You also use a few too many "if" statements in places where you don't need them.

Next is your concern about multiple servers. This is really not a problem if you write the code to be dynamic. The execution of the command is quick enough that you don't need to worry about two people trying to use the command and the roles getting mixed up.

What I would really advise you to do is take a look at this https://discordjs.guide/ and this https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

Now to the topic of this question, this is how you could do such a "verify" command. I also added a few notations into the code to explain what we're doing

```
client.on("message", message => { // You don't need the async here
    
    // This is all working correctly
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
    
    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === "verify") {

        // We define the server constant as the part of the JSON that deals with the server the message came from
        // This makes accessing those values easier
        const server = config.server[message.guild.id];
        
        // Your code here was also working
        let member = message.mentions.members.first();

        // Here we first define the moderator role
        // Technicaly this is not needed but it makes the whole code a little easier to understand
        // We need modrole[0] here because the modrole entry in your JSON is an array
        let modrole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === server.modroles[0]);

        // Here we check if the member who calls this command has the needed role
        // We need to use the ID of the role to check
        if (!message.member.roles.cache.has(modrole.id)) {
            // If the user does not have the required role we return here
            // That way you don't need to use the 'else' statement
            // Creating the embed object in multiple lines improves readability
            return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Missing Perms!")
                .setDescription("You're missing the permission to execute this command!")
                .setColor(0xe74c3c)
            );
        }

        if (!member) {
            // Here we check if a member was tagged in the command and if that user exists
            // Same reasons as above
            return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(0xd35400)
                .setTitle("Invalid User")
                .setDescription(`Please use the following Syntax:\n '${config.prefix}verify <Nutzer>'`)
            );
        }

        // Now we define the role that we want the bot to give
        // Here we also don't need to do this but it improves readability and makes working with the role a little easier
        var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === server.verifiedrole);

        // Here we add the role to the specified member
        // We don't need to use the .cache here
        member.roles.add(role.id);
        // We can use something called "template strings" here so we don't need to combine multiple strings
        // They allow us to put predefined values into the string
        console.log(`Command used: ${command} ${args} | User: ${message.author.id} | Guild: ${message.guild.id}`)
    }


})
```

Comment: Not sure if you still need this but hey... 

Answer (score -1):

If you want, that the command can be executed at multiple servers at the time you need to write the code in `async/await`. If you want to learn more about async you can get very good help especially for discord.js v12 here: [Understanding async/await](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html)

Answer (score -1):

you can get a command for a specifiq channel and give a role for acces to the  server